# ios 6 pull to refresh

Tags: ios, uirefreshcontrol

I've implemented the new pull to refresh method in my app, adding the following code to viewDidLoad:

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
```

The method handleRefresh loads some data from a DB and then refreshes the tableview.
This method only get called when the user is pulling the tableview.
Now I'd like to manually call the handleRefresh method because at some point I'm deleting some items from the DB and I need to load data again, before reloading the tableview.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `[self handleRefresh:nil]`

Comment: How are you calling this method? Are you sure you come to this line?

Comment: There must be something else wrong in my code. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: So mark the question has resolved and go back to your debugger :)